For FirebaseMessaging, is dryRun set to false needed to uncover more UNREGISTERED scenarios?
FirebaseMessaging has a sendAsync method with boolean dryRun as its second parameter. I've seen sendAsync throw a FirebaseMessagingException with error code UNREGISTERED when dryRun is true and I've seen sendAsync throw a FirebaseMessagingException with error code UNREGISTERED when dryRun is false.
However, I'm looking to understand: does dryRun set to false cause UNREGISTERED scenario(s) that dryRun set to true does not cause?
Edit: I was initially seeing examples where dry run true wasn't revealing all UNREGISTERED scenario(s), but I'm no longer seeing that. Firebase has resolved this issue.

The relevant documentation is pretty clear about it:

If the dryRun option is set to true, the message will not be actually sent to the recipients. Instead, the FCM service performs all the necessary validations, and emulates the send operation. This is a good way to check if a certain message will be accepted by FCM for delivery.

In order to avoid that FirebaseMessagingException with MessagingErrorCode.UNREGISTERED, one has to validate all the tokens, in order to determine, which are still registered and the remove those, which are not registered anymore. The part with "and a new one must be used" might not be that clear, because this most often might mean, the user has to install the app again, in order to be assigned a new one token for the new one app instance.

App instance was unregistered from FCM. This usually means that the token used is no longer valid and a new one must be used.


And to answer your actual question: This depends which token you send to.
dryRun is exactly the same, except that the notification/s will not be sent out.
The confusion might have been caused by an uninstall and reinstall, while still sending to the same FCM token. While the term "app instance" effectively refers to an instance of an app installation.
After having removed all unregistered tokens, these's no MessagingErrorCode.UNREGISTERED anymore, at least not until someone will uninstall the app, while will cause the associated token to be unregistered. I'd assume, one could also remove on error-code, but I'd still prefer batch-mode.

"dryRun is exactly the same, except that the notification/s will not be sent out." Unfortunately, this is not correct. I am seeing some that dry run = true returns UNREGISTERED for some expiration scenarios, but not all expiration scenarios.

When this is with the same token, same payload and the app won't be uninstalled, this might be a server-side issue. Generally one does not even need any dryRun, while it works and while maintaining the tokens properly. Tagging in people somehow doesn't work anymore; just open a support ticket, if this would have any relavance.
